# (Re)newDocumentCommand interferes with the layout

Tags: ieeetran, xparse

While preparing a paper using the `IEEEtran` class in `conference` mode, I was overloading the `\end` command using `\RenewDocumentCommand` (for personnal use). The result is that an extra blank line is added to the authors:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{xparse}

\title{An unimportant paper}
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{First author}
\IEEEauthorblockA{address}}

% \let\oldend\end
% \RenewDocumentCommand\end{m}{\oldend{#1}}

\begin{document} 
\maketitle
------------------------- 
\end{document}
```

When uncommenting the two commented line, an extra blank line appears below the authors (and above the `---------`line). It comes from a `\crcr`command when displaying the authors. This phenomenon does not occur when `\renewcommand` is used instead of `\RenewDocumentCommand`.

My questions are thus the following:
- Why does this happen?
- Though it is very easy to solve in this case, is there a way to know in advance when such phenomena can occur?

Comment: Do you *really* want to modify `\end`?

Comment: I am tracking the structure of the document with as much precision as possible. The simplest way I have found to do so is to overload `\begin` and `\end` (as well as `\section`, `\item`, ...).

Comment: Track how? and for what?

Comment: @daleif: This would require a long answer. For short, I am writing/using a package for hyperlinking a lot of information inside a document: for instance the use of a term poiting to the location of its definition. However, a variable or a term may only be used in, say, some proof, or locally in some section, and have another meaning in some other place of the document. The package (helped with some writer's command) should be able to understand things like "the variable x I am talking about here is the one that was introduced in Theorem 3.2".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem shows essentially with `tabular`, because the `\endtabular` command is seen too late if `\end` has been redefined with `\RenewDocumentCommand`.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{xparse}

\let\oldend\end
\RenewDocumentCommand\end{m}{\oldend{#1}}

\begin{document} 

\hrule
\begin{tabular}{c}
xyz \\
uvw \\
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{c}
xyz \\
uvw \\
foo \\
\oldend{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{c}
xyz \\
uvw \\
\oldend{tabular}
\hrule

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, the second `tabular` is aligned to the first one, whereas the third one has no additional row.

It's not because of some `\crcr` as you suspect.

- `\\` ends a row.
- Now LaTeX looks whether there's `\hline` or similar command and expands tokens as it goes.
- If it finds `\omit` or `\noalign`, it performs the appropriate actions (the former would come from `\multicolumn`, the latter from `\hline`).
- Other commands start a cell.

Among the “other commands” are all those defined as `\protected`: by programmer's choice, they stop the search for `\omit` and `\noalign`.

Thus `\end` is expanded when a table cell has already started, so a new row appears.

Every macro defined with `\NewDocumentCommand`, `\RenewDocumentCommand` or `\DeclareDocumentCommand` is `\protected`. Not those defined with `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand`.

By the way, you see the issue with `\maketitle` because there is a `tabular` in its workings.

Answer (score 7):

`\end` has to be expandable.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{xparse}

\title{An unimportant paper}
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{First author}
\IEEEauthorblockA{address}}

\let\oldend\end
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand\end{m}{\oldend{#1}}

\begin{document} 
\maketitle
------------------------- 
\end{document}
```

*N.B.:* Why don’t you use `\AtEndDocument{...}`?

Comment: I do not undersand why `\end` has to be expandable. Is it an obvious fact? In fact, this is the first time I see this phenomenon occur, while I am using similar code overloadig `\end` for quite some time.
N.B: as I was answering @egreg, the goal is to catch all the `\begin` and `\end` in the document, not just the last one!

Comment: @ThomasColcombet The author block is typeset in a construction called `@IEEEauthorhalign`.  The `\end` part of this command is `\def\end@IEEEauthorhalign{\crcr\egroup\egroup}`.  The `\crcr` inside this is not “seen” if it is protected and added too late resulting in an extra newline.

Comment: @Henri: Thanks. egreg's post is describing the phenomenon in detail, and now everything is clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

Without `xparse`

```
\let\oldend\end
\renewcommand\end{\oldend}
```

Comment: I know this solution, of course. But it does not hlp me forsee when it may hapen again...